# How to call a AS/400 function from a Java Class

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpg

I need to call from a Java Class a RPG Function, i found a bunch of examples that show how to do that, but the thing is that my function when is compile is a MODULE not a PGM. And when i try to call it show me a message that the object doesn't exist.

I execute the command WRKOBJ *ALL/FUNCTION_NAME there is the object.

Someone has a clue if i can make a call from a Java Class to a RPG Function.

I've done make a call to a RPG or CL from a Java Class but not to a Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a function in a *MODULE object.

A module is an intermediate object that is not executable.    You have to bind the module into a *PGM or *SRVPGM object which are executable.

Comment: Ok, now i got it. Thank you Charles for your help i appreciate.